# How do you match a caret (^) symbol in regex?

Tags: regex, caret

I know these won't do it and also why, but how do you match it?

```
/^/
/(^)/
/[^]/
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Escape it with a backslash:

```
/\^/
```

This will make it be interpreted as a literal `^` character.

Answer (score 8):

I think this works (I've tested this in java):

```
\\^
```

'\' is used as an escape character, so you first escape '^', then you escape '\' itself

you can find more information here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

Comment: That's not the reason that two backslashes are needed here -- the first one escapes the second one in the string literal, and then the resulting `\^` gets passed to the regex engine, which uses the backslash to escape the `^`. Languages which support regexes as special literals (generally with the `/.../` syntax) instead of using strings don't have this problem.

Comment: you're right, but apart from any language this: \^ should generally work  with regex