# Preventing users from sending Caret symbols.

Tags: c#, regex

I have a model that has an attribute called **UserCustomMessage** below you can see how that attribute is set in my model.

I need to make sure users do not send in a Caret symbol since that will create issues later on in my code. I need for my regular expression to literally find any **^** symbols and return the error message **Invalid character in User Custom Message.**

According to this article 
[How do you match a caret (^) symbol in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524583/how-do-you-match-a-caret-symbol-in-regex)

The symbol I have placed in my regular expression should take every literal instances of the Caret symbol however it does not, and the request goes through. What is the best way of doing this?

```
[RegularExpression(@"[/\^/]", ErrorMessage = "Invalid character in User Custom Message.")]
public string UserCustomMessage { get; set; }
```

Comment: It does match any caret symbol take a look at https://ideone.com/sq8nEf

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET? Are you sure your `RegularExpressionAttribute` does what you think it does and is working?

Comment: @marvel308 it seems as though your expressiong is **string pattern = @"\^";** I will try with that see how it goes .

Comment: @marvel308 I changed my model to **[RegularExpression(@"\^", ErrorMessage = "Invalid character in Merchant Custom Message.")]** and the Caret character is still going through. Is there no way of placing it in the model?

Comment: [/\^/] would match /,\ or ^

Comment: @marvel308 I just ran another test it seems as though the brackets were the issue. **[RegularExpression(@"/\^/", ErrorMessage = "Invalid character in Merchant Custom Message.")]** worked for me

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t escape the carets instead of disallowing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[/\^/]
```

would match **/, \ or ^**

you can use the regex

```
@"/\^/"
```

to match it see it in the [online compiler](https://ideone.com/sq8nEf)

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what you need to put as a header of your attribute in order to ONLY stop the user from sending a string with a Caret symbol.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[^\^]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid character in User Custom Message.")]
public string UserCustomMessage { get; set; }
```